# Is there a way to return the "Body" of an Outlook email as a string and not HTML using Office Script?

Tags: power-automate, excel-online, office-scripts

I want to extend the "[Pass data to scripts in an automatically-run Power Automate flow (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/tutorials/excel-power-automate-trigger)" tutorial to include the Body parameter of an email.

```
function main(
  workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook,
  from: string,
  dateReceived: string,
  subject: string
  body: string) {

}
```

The input of 'body', however, returns the email as HTML. To handle this, I am parsing the string to pull out the body tag only. Is there a more standard way of doing this?

I found on the [Office 365 Outlook connectors docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#when-a-new-email-arrives-(v3)) that 'Body' is under 'Return' and not 'Parameters'. Is this what is preventing a return of the body tag string contents?

Thank you for any answers or suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You might have to tweak the code a little bit since I don't know how your emails will look. But here is how I would figure it out.

[image]

[image]

Here is what the email looks like for the example.

[image]

Here is the code I used to extract the body. Notice how I use "array(1)", because "array(0)" would be "Hi Test," and "array(2)" would be "Thanks,"

[image]

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, from: string, dateReceived:string, subject: string, body: string) {
  let array = body.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
  body = array[1];
  let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet3").getRange("A1:D1").setValues([[from, dateReceived, subject, body]]);
}
```